# Text-bottom in Opera

Tags: css, opera

The following doesn't work in Opera:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
p {font:10pt Arial; background:green; height:16px;}
img {width:16px; height:16px; vertical-align:text-bottom;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>An <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-16.png" alt=""> image with a text-bottom alignment.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: @JamesMontagne: The image position doesn't look right. I tried it in other browsers with no problem.

Comment: doesn't look right? it doesn't vertical align as you want? can you post a screen? here i can't see what could be wrong http://jsfiddle.net/25K9y/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are right, it seems to be a Opera bug

http://jsfiddle.net/vfcVR/ (renders correctly on firefox and chrome, not on opera)

Bug examples: (highlight text around `<img>` to see where the image is actually rendered)

- http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/Opera12Bugs/vertical-align-text-bottom.html
- http://www.css-lab.com/bug-test/opera-img-va-bug.html

you could try using `vertical-align:bottom` instead, but that is not a "workaround" since you have to use `line-height:1` for to have what you're looking for :(

hope this helps..